# Show that this joint density function of X and Y is in fact a density

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function, advice

We have this density are asked to verify if the double integral over $R^2$ of the density evaluates to $1$ (the second part of the problem asks to find the expectation of $X$). The density given is $f(x,y) = \frac35(5 - 3x - 2y), 0 < x + y < 1$, and $0$ otherwise.

I am having some trouble setting up the bounds of integration. I tried to sketch a graph which is simply two parallel lines, the first: $y = 1 -x$, the second: $y = -x$. So we are interested in integrating over the region enclosed by the two parallel lines. Therefore, I setup the following integral:

$1 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_x^{1-x}f(x,y)dydx$. But this integral does not converge. So either I have the wrong bounds for my integrals or am going wrong somewhere else, but not sure where. Looking for some hint on how to proceed.

Comment: The density has to be non-negative - $3x+2y\le 5$.

Comment: $\int _0^1\int _0^{1-x}\frac{1}{5} 3 (-3 x-2 y+5)dydx==1$.  But so does $\int _{-\frac{1}{10}}^{0.7283}\int _{\frac{1}{10}}^{\min (1,1-x)}\frac{1}{5} 3 (-3 x-2 y+5)dydx=1$.  So I wonder if there is no unique area for which $f(x,y)$ is a legit bivariate density.  Is there a missing $x\geq 0$ and $y\geq 0$?

Comment: @JimB Hmm.. it's possible that those constraints were implied by the problem creator. I will find out